# Can you customize the border of ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

It seems like Apple doesn't really want us messing with the presentation of the Sign In With Apple button - is there a way to make the border thicker, for example, or change the color?

It seems like we could set the `cornerRadius` *and* the `...button.layer.cornerRadius` to the same value maybe; we're looking for something cleaner.

Happy to clarify if needed!

Comment: Just add another shape behind it, make it a little bit larger and set the color to the border you want

Comment: @Evan Yup, definitely thought about this, good call.

Comment: @ArielSD glad I could help

Comment: how to add image instead ... ?

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon It looks like the button comes with an Apple icon already. If you haven't seen this, this is a great place to start: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/